# GitKraken And Github - failed to get server certificate: The handle is in the wrong state for the requested operation

Tags: github, gitkraken

I am getting this error message from GitKraken whenever I try to clone/fetch/push/push to any of my Github repositories:

> failed to get server certificate: The handle is in the wrong state for the requested operation

I have no idea why this is happening, everything was working fine with my current setup until yesterday and I have checked that GitKraken is properly authorized to connect to my Github account and my repositories.

**What I have tried:**

- Remove and add my credentials, reauthorize GitKraken.
- Check my Git installation - can correctly push/pull and clone Github repos.
- Tested on another machine, I can reproduce the issue.
- Reinstalled GitKraken.
- Run as administrator.
- Removed the `.gitkraken` folder under `%AppData%` and reconnected from scratch.
- Installed the [kb3140245](http://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/search.aspx?q=kb3140245) update as suggested in the GitKraken Slack channel to someone else with a similar issue.
- Generated and added SSH keys via the GitKraken UI to connect to Github.

**Technical Information:**

- GitKraken version: 3.3.4
- OS: Windows 7 Ultimate (x64)

Anyone else have a similar problem or know how to deal with this?

**PS:** I am not entirely sure what other technical information might be of use to troubleshoot the issue, so feel free to ask me in the comments below to update my question with any relevant information.

Comment: Just for the record...can you clone, push and pull, using https instead of ssh, right?

Comment: @Hackerman I can do that from terminal, if that's what you meant. GitKraken cannot do any of these actions no matter what I do.

Comment: Yeah, I have a friend with the same issue. What could be the problem? Does anyone here know how to fix this?

Comment: @ThiagoYoithi The accepted answer is actually correct and fixes the issue. This is a problem on Github's side, stemming from their decision to stop supporting TLS 1.1 or below.

Comment: Does someone has an answer for the same problem on Windows 10 ?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This is because Github removed weak cryptophic standard support (TLSv1 and TLSv1.1) - [source](https://github.com/blog/2507-weak-cryptographic-standards-removed)

All you have to do on Windows devices (mostly on Windows 7) is set default TLS version to 1.2 - [link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3140245/update-to-enable-tls-1-1-and-tls-1-2-as-a-default-secure-protocols-in)

### Step-by-step fix

1. Download the [kb3140245](http://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/search.aspx?q=kb3140245) update from Microsoft, which is necessary to enable TLS 1.1 and TLS 1.2.
2. Download the [easy fix utility](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3140245/update-to-enable-tls-1-1-and-tls-1-2-as-a-default-secure-protocols-in#easy) from Microsoft and run it.
3. Restart your system. Everything should work fine. There might be issues with some websites etc, just rebooting your router should resolve any issues that might arise.

Answer (score 9):

This broke me for a long time.

In gitkraken, go to the left window where "origin" is on your respective repos, click the three dots over flow and click "edit origin", make sure your pull & push urls are ssh or http **NOT** https.