# Windows 10 GitKraken And Github - failed to get server certificate: The handle is in the wrong state for the requested operation

Tags: github, gitkraken

I noticed the fix on the below thread for windows 7 but I am seeing it on windows 10, multiple boxes at my work and others reporting on gitkraken slack channel.

Anyone fixed this on windows 10?

Windows 7 thread link:
[GitKraken And Github - failed to get server certificate: The handle is in the wrong state for the requested operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48985995/gitkraken-and-github-failed-to-get-server-certificate-the-handle-is-in-the-wr)

Comment: Any luck with this error, I'm also facing a similar issue? Please post an answer, if you have fixed this issue.

Comment: also experiencing, just randomly started happening today

Comment: Using `http` instead of `https` worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

#### UPDATE: This is not recommended as all traffic will be send over HTTP instead of HTTPS.

This means everything will be visible (not encrypted) to anyone watching network activity. Please see the comment from cboittin below

---

**Credit to [Kef](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7262197/kef) in the comments.**
Changing the remote origin from `https` to `http` fixed it for me. **(Again, not recommended)**

> Disclaimer: <s>I do not know if this has any side effects. If it does, please let me know in the comments.</s>

### How to change the remote origin address in gitkraken:

You can change it from https by checking the left navigation bar and clicking the `3 dots` button next to the remote origin. (Image)

[image]

After that click **edit origin**.
Here you can see the `pull` and `push` addresses. Changing those from `https` to `http` fixed it for me.

[image]

Comment: I do not recommend doing that. All your operations on that repo will be sent in clear, which means anyone sniffing your traffic will be able to see the entire content of your repo. If working with a private repo, this is probably not what you want. It probably also opens up the possibility for some more aggressive attacks. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/11622001/5078353

Comment: I'll edit the answer to reflect this, thanks for letting me now! (Or is it better to just remove it you think?)