# Gitkraken can't access private repo via HTTPS

Tags: git, https, bitbucket-server, gitkraken, certificate-store

I am working for a new client and am trying to introduce Gitkraken but got stuck at an error where it says `Pull Failed: failed to get server certificate: The handle is in the wrong state for the requested operation`.

Here is some context, I need to access a private repo outside company domain and for security reasons I can't use SSH or HTTP for that, only HTTPS and had a certificate installed to do so which I have done and works fine on git via command line and direct browser access.

I have looked on past questions about it (especially [on Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48985995/gitkraken-and-github-failed-to-get-server-certificate-the-handle-is-in-the-wr) and [on Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49308343/windows-10-gitkraken-and-github-failed-to-get-server-certificate-the-handle-i)) but none of the paths provided have been successful so far.

Edit: I don't have admin access to the computer I want to use Gitkraken with. I am using Windows 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got in touch with Gitkraken support and this is a known issue. Unfortunately there is no ETA on when it is going to be fixed.