# make GitKraken forget GitHub credentials

Tags: gitkraken

I cloned a project from Github, which went well. Then I pulled once and accidently entered the wrong credentials. Now I always get "failed to get server certificate: The handle is in the wrong state for the requested operation". So this looks like [that problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48985995/) but it can't be that TLS issue because cloning from that Github repo worked just a few minutes before (not anymore now). How can I make GitKraken forget my Github credentials? Settings→Integrations→GitHub→Disconnect did not do the trick. Adding a GitKraken SSH key to GitHub did not help either.

Update: Now I tried [Forget All](https://support.gitkraken.com/integrations/authentication/#forget-all). The problem now is that GitKraken is asking me again and again for my credentials. But login to GitHub in browsers work. Why?

Answer (score 0):

In the end I cloned the project again. Maybe this workaround also works for others.